# Solving a block tridiagonal system with diagonal perturbations

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices

Say we have a block tridiagonal matrix, $T \in \mathbb{R}^{NL \times NL}$, with constant off diagonals, $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{L\times L}$, given by

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A}_1 & \mathbf{B} & \boldsymbol{0} & \cdots & 0\\
                    \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{A}_2 & \mathbf{B} & \cdots & 0\\
                      & & & \ddots & \\
                      & & & \mathbf{A}_{N-1} & \mathbf{B} \\
                      & & & \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{A}_N\end{bmatrix}
$$
I am trying to determine the following:  is there a way to factor $T$, so that if we first solve $T \mathbf{x}_1 = \mathbf{y}$ and later have to solve $(T + P) \mathbf{x}_2 = (\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{p})$, where $P = \text{diag}\left(P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_N \right)$ each $P_i \in \mathbf{R}^{L \times L}$,  and $p \in \mathbf{R}^{NL}$, then we can find $\mathbf{x}_2$ cheaper now than if we had never solved the first system?  i.e. is there an algorithm / factorization of block tridiagonal systems that makes solving diagonal block perturbations more efficient?

I have not come across anything in the literature that discusses purely diagonal perturbations to block tridiagonal systems; Reuter et al. 2012 [1] is the closest work I have found, but it deals with general deviations along the diagonal.

[1] Reuter et al. 2012, [An efficient, block-by-block algorithm for inverting a block tridiagonal, nearly block Toeplitz matrix](https://doi.org/10.1088/1749-4699/5/1/014009)

Comment: Solving the perturbed system from scratch already has a cost that is linear in $N$, like the size of the input and the output, so there isn't much room for improvement here.

Comment: Sure this is true, but most algorithms for solving these systems scale on the order of $\mathcal{O}(N L^3)$, and this $L^3$ can become prohibitive.  So given we have already solved the original system, I was curious if there were a way to solve the perturbed system, perhaps avoiding the $L^3$ complexity.